# Code signing Java ME application for Myriad Java, Esmertec Java

Tags: java, java-me, code-signing, certificate-authority

[myriad java screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg3ms.png)I have a Java ME application that I need to sign, but I don't know the  Certificate Authority (CA) that are supported by the device. I searched and it seems like there is no way to get a list of supported CA from code. I downloaded many signed applications but I wasn't able to install them because the phone does not support the CA they use. I had no luck in contacting the phone manufacturer nor the company that provides the JVM and all the CA want me to pay full price and promise they will give me the money back if their certificate is not supported. The phone I am targeting is a chinese feature phone very popular in India and many other countries. It is running a JVM own by "Myriad". According to my research Esmertec made the JVM then Myriad bought Esmertec. If one of you ever signed a Java ME app that works properly on Esmertec or Myriad Java please provide guidance.